# Factoring WHERE clauses in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I recovered some spaghetti code and I have to refactor it. I do not want a method with over 200 lines, for me it is not object oriented programming . I am trying to ponder on the question, I would like to have your suggestions.

This is my code:

**Line 18**

```
if (searchCriteria.EventReference != null)
{
    query = query.Search(x = > x.EventReference, searchCriteria.EventReference);
}
if (searchCriteria.PendingEvent == false)
{
    query = query.Where(x = > x.EventStatusId != EventStatus.Pending);
}
if (searchCriteria.VerifiedEvent == false)
{
    query = query.Where(x = > x.EventStatusId != EventStatus.Verified);
}
if (searchCriteria.CanceledEvent == false)
{
    query = query.Where(x = > x.EventStatusId != EventStatus.Canceled);
}
```

**Line 237**

```
if (searchCriteria.RemitterId != null)
{
    query = query.Where(x = > x.Trade.RemitterId == searchCriteria.RemitterId);
}
```

Comment: This is a good question for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Object programming or not, this is the correct way of building dynamic filters. You can always extract some parts of the big method to their own methods, as with any regular method refactoring, there is nothing in common with `Where` and `IQueryable`.

Comment: If numer of lines is your concern, then remove `{ }` brackets from `if` conditions, you will decrease two lines for each condition :)

Comment: surely EventStatusId can only have a value equal to one of your EventStatus' therefore you could refactor your searchCriteria to contain a field called EventType and remove PendingEvent, VerifiedEvent and CancelledEvent. Then you can replace those ifs with query.Where(x => x.EventStatusId = searchCriteria.EventType);

Comment: @AdilMammadov Certainly, remove braces can reduce the number of lines, but I think a smarter solution, where we can have more object programming. for example, create a class with properties corresponding to the number of IF(..) and constructor initializes all checks. And so it can be used in the calling method...whatever somme thing like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to be overkill to me (but I guess it's the polymorphism that appears in the comments), but anyway, there it is:

We start with an interface:

```
public interface IQueryFilter
{
    IQueryable<Whatever> Filter(IQueryable<Whatever> query, SearchCriteria searchCriteria);
}
```

Then implement the common property:

```
public abstract class AQueryFilter<T> : IQueryFilter
{
    public AQueryFilter(Func<SearchCriteria, T> criteria)
    {
        Criteria = criteria;
    }

    protected Func<SearchCriteria, T> Criteria { get; }
    public abstract IQueryable<Whatever> Filter(IQueryable<Whatever> query, SearchCriteria searchCriteria);
}
```

And finally, all the specific stuff:

```
public class WhereEventStatusQueryFilter : AQueryFilter<bool>
{
    private EventStatus _toTest;

    public WhereEventStatusQueryFilter(Func<SearchCriteria, bool> criteria, EventStatus toTest)
        : base(criteria)
    {
        _toTest = toTest;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Whatever> Filter(IQueryable<Whatever> query, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        return (Criteria(searchCriteria) ? query : query.Where(x => x.EventStatusId != _toTest));
    }
}

public class SearchQueryFilter : AQueryFilter<object>
{
    Func<Whatever, object> _searchFor;

    public SearchQueryFilter(Func<SearchCriteria, object> criteria, Func<Whatever, object> searchFor)
        : base(criteria)
    {
        _searchFor = searchFor;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Whatever> Filter(IQueryable<Whatever> query, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        return (Criteria(searchCriteria) == null ? query : query.Search(x => _searchFor(x), Criteria(searchCriteria)));
    }
}

public class WhereEqualQueryFilter : AQueryFilter<object>
{
    Func<Whatever, object> _searchFor;

    public WhereEqualQueryFilter(Func<SearchCriteria, object> criteria, Func<Whatever, object> searchFor)
        : base(criteria)
    {
        _searchFor = searchFor;
    }

    public override IQueryable<Whatever> Filter(IQueryable<Whatever> query, SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        return (Criteria(searchCriteria) == null ? query : query.Where(x => _searchFor(x) == Criteria(searchCriteria)));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var filters = new IQueryFilter[]
{
    new WhereEventStatusQueryFilter(x => x.PendingEvent, EventStatus.Pending),
    new WhereEventStatusQueryFilter(x => x.VerifiedEvent, EventStatus.Verified),
    new SearchQueryFilter(x => x.EventReference, x => x.EventReference),
    new WhereEqualQueryFilter(x => x.RemittedId, x => x.Trade.RemittedId),
    ...
};

foreach (var filter in filters)
    query = filter.Filter(query, searchCriteria);
```

But this solution hide a lot of the logic. And if anyone wants to add something he has to read all the previous filter classes to know if there is already one that can get the job done or if he has to write another one.

Comment: beautiful, thanks :).  some people downvote arbitrary

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that is really better, but you could do something like this:

```
var searchDict = new Dictionary<Func<bool>, Func<IQueryable<?>>>()
{
    { () => searchCriteria.EventReference != null, query.Search(x = > x.EventReference, searchCriteria.EventReference) },
    { () => searchCriteria.VerifiedEvent == false, query.Where(x = > x.EventStatusId != EventStatus.Verified) },
    { () => searchCriteria.RemitterId != null, query.Where(x = > x.Trade.RemitterId == searchCriteria.RemitterId) },
    ...
};

foreach (var item in seachDict)
    if (item.First())
        query = item.Second();
```

or (depending on where and how you want to create your dictionary):

```
var searchDict = new Dictionary<Func<SearchCriteria, bool>, Func<IQueryable<?>, IQueryable<?>>>()
{
    { c => c.EventReference != null, q => q.Search(x = > x.EventReference, searchCriteria.EventReference)},
    { c => c.VerifiedEvent == false, q => q.Where(x = > x.EventStatusId != EventStatus.Verified) },
    { c => c.RemitterId != null, q => q.Where(x = > x.Trade.RemitterId == searchCriteria.RemitterId) },
    ...
};

foreach (var item in seachDict)
    if (item.First(searchCriteria))
        query = item.Second(query);
```

Comment: the dictionary is a good idea, why not. but I want object programming. but your idea is not bad

Comment: Thanks :) I will come up later with another solution if no one answer it with objects.